# (PHP) strtotime function false positive with char

Tags: php, validation, date, laravel-5.3, strtotime

I don't understand why this is a valid date

```
strtotime("1920-09k-12") // -1556877600 // I expect false
```

I see that adding a char after the month or day is a valid date.

```
strtotime("1920-09-12d") // -1555905600 // I expect false
strtotime("1920-09n-12") // -1556838000 // I expect false
```

Instead

```
strtotime("1920-09k-12k") // false
strtotime("1920r-09-12") // false
strtotime("1920-09-12") // -1555862400
```

Is this the expected behaviour?

I use Laravel and the strtotime function is used for validate date in the framework but when go to save a record in DB with a "false positive" date a QueryException is raised.
I resolved the problem with a custom validation but i'm curious to know why strtotime has this behaviour.

Comment: Did you try the `Carbon` class which is included in laravel?

Comment: Yes i use Carbon but can't change the framework validation rule.
Anyway the problem is with strtotime not with the framework.
I just solved my problem in the project but i want know why strtotime has not the expected behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not fully answer your question, but examining the results of [`date_parse()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-parse.php) for your sample dates, it appears that the first letter in the string is interpreted as the timezone, and the remainder of the string as well, which either causes a warning or an error of `"Double timezone specification"`, and in the case of an error, the `DateTime` cannot be created.

For example:

**`date_parse("1920-09-12d")`**

```
Array
(
    [year] => 1920
    [month] => 9
    [day] => 12
    [hour] => 
    [minute] => 
    [second] => 
    [fraction] => 
    [warning_count] => 0
    [warnings] => Array
        (
        )

    [error_count] => 0
    [errors] => Array
        (
        )

    [is_localtime] => 1
    [zone_type] => 2
    [zone] => -240
    [is_dst] => 
    [tz_abbr] => D
)
```

*Notice the timezone "D"*

---

**`date_parse("1920-09n-12")`**

```
Array
(
    [year] => 1920
    [month] => 9
    [day] => 1
    [hour] => 
    [minute] => 
    [second] => 
    [fraction] => 
    [warning_count] => 1
    [warnings] => Array
        (
            [8] => Double timezone specification
        )

    [error_count] => 0
    [errors] => Array
        (
        )

    [is_localtime] => 1
    [zone_type] => 2
    [zone] => 60
    [is_dst] => 
    [tz_abbr] => N
)
```

*Notice the timezone "N", furthermore the 12 is not interpreted as the day of month, but rather I suspect "-12" is interpreted as an additional timezone specification, hence the warning.*

---

**`date_parse("1920r-09-12")`**

```
Array
(
    [year] => 
    [month] => 
    [day] => 
    [hour] => 19
    [minute] => 20
    [second] => 0
    [fraction] => 
    [warning_count] => 1
    [warnings] => Array
        (
            [5] => Double timezone specification
        )

    [error_count] => 1
    [errors] => Array
        (
            [8] => Double timezone specification
        )

    [is_localtime] => 1
    [zone_type] => 2
    [zone] => 300
    [is_dst] => 
    [tz_abbr] => R
)
```

*Notice the timezone "R", furthermore no date is parsed, rather `1920` is interpreted as the time `19:20:00`, and I suspect the remainder of the string is interpreted as 2 timezones, "-09" & "-12", causing the error "Double timezone specification".*

Comment: thx for your answer, it all makes sense now for me. I never try date_parse function. Maybe is more useful for validations than strtotime.